# java lambdaj 'variable_name' cannot be resolved to a variable error

Tags: java-8, java-stream, lambdaj

I am new to Java 8 features and this may be a stupid question but I am stuck at this point.

I am trying to run following code in eclipse but it gives compile time error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import ch.lambdaj.Lambda;

public class LambdajTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(16);

        int sum = list.stream().filter(p -> p > 10).mapToInt(p -> p).sum();
    }

}
```

Error is :- p cannot be resolved to a variable.
I have added lambdaj 2.3.3 jar at classpath.

Kindly provide solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to declare p as int in the lambda expression

Comment: Your code does not need LambdaJ. LambdaJ is mainly a library that provides nice collection methods and is targeted to Java < 8. It has nothing to do with Java 8 Lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the JVM doesn't know what kind of object `p` is as you're using a raw collection.

Change

`List list = new ArrayList();`

to

`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

The JVM now understands that it's streaming over a collection of `Integer` objects.

Comment: Makes more sense than what I thought it was.